# Can I do some initializations before `Inherited Create`?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to create and start a thread, all with one command line `TClientCopyThread.Create(...)`. For this, I must create the thread with `Suspended = False`, so that it can run immediately. I know that when I write a `constructor` of a new object, first of all  I must call the `inherited Create` so that the instance of the object is created, and then do my initializations. But here, if I call `inherited` the thread will start without initialized parameters. I try to call `inherited` last and it seems it's working (I don't receive any access violation), but I don't know for sure if this is a coincidence or not.

```
  TClientCopyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    OwnGUID: String;
    SrcPath, DestPath: String;
    Files: TFileNames;
    RemoveIt: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const GUID, ASrcPath, ADestPath: String;
     const FileNames: TFileNames; RemoveSrc: Boolean);
  end;

constructor TClientCopyThread.Create(const GUID, ASrcPath, ADestPath: String;
 const FileNames: TFileNames; RemoveSrc: Boolean);
var I: Integer;
begin
 SrcPath:=  Copy(ASrcPath, 1, Length(ASrcPath));
 DestPath:= Copy(ADestPath, 1, Length(ADestPath));
 SetLength(Files, Length(FileNames));
 for I:= 0 to High(Files) do
  Files[I]:= Copy(FileNames[I], 1, Length(FileNames[I]));
 RemoveIt:= RemoveSrc;
 FreeOnTerminate:= True;
 inherited Create;
end;
```

Comment: A good place to start the thread is in AfterConstruction where all constructors have been executed and the instance should be stable.

Comment: @J... I thought about that too, but I get an error message if I try to `Start` the thread from constructor. / Ok, so the memory for my new object is already allocated when I enter in constructor ?

Comment: @UweRaabe `TThread` already does *exactly* that when `CreateSuspended=False`

Comment: @MarusNebunu `TThread.Start()` raises an `EThread` exception if the `TThread` object was created with `CreateSuspended=False`, or if the thread has already finished running, or if `Start()` has already been called, or if the `TThread` pointer was obtained from calling `TThread.CurrentThread` in a non-`TThread` thread. So, it should be perfectly safe to call `Start()` inside a derived constructor when using `inherited Create(True)`. If that is not working, then that is a bug that would need to be fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your specific question - YES, you can call `inherited Create` at any point during a derived constructor.  It DOES NOT need to be the first statement (same with `inherited Destroy` as the last statement in the destructor).  Memory for the class object has already been allocated in full before *any* constructors are called, so it is safe to initialize members of your derived class before calling the `inherited` constructor. However, when accessing base class members from the derived constructor, you should call the `inherited` constructor first to initialize them before accessing them.

That being said, your understanding of how the `TThread` constructor works is just plain wrong.  Since Delphi 6 onwards, the base class `TThread` constructor *always* creates the underlying OS thread in suspended mode, and then resumes the thread in `TThread.AfterConstruction()` after *all* constructors have fully exited, if the `TThread` object is constructed with `CreateSuspended=False`.  So, your claim that calling `inherited Create` with `CreateSuspended=False` will start the thread running *immediately* has NOT been true since 2001 when Delphi 6 was released.  The underlying OS thread will NOT start running until *after* your `TClientCopyThread.Create()` constructor has exited.  Thus, your `Execute()` method will *never* act on uninitialized members, regardless of how you set `CreateSuspended`.

What you describe (the thread running before members were initialized) was a *bug* in Delphi 5 and earlier, which was fixed in Delphi 6.

Comment: This holds true only if parent class isn't creating any internal/nested objects/classes in its own constructor. If it is then not calling `inherited Create` fast enough would mean that you might try to access these objects from derived class constructor before they were properly created which would then cause Access Violation. So yeah while this do holds true with TThread class since it does not have any internal objects it many not hold true with other classes.

Comment: @SilverWarior obviously, if a derived class constructor wants to access base class members, it needs to call the `inherited` constructor first to initialize those members. But that call does not *need* to be the *first* statement in the derived constructor of not desired, though that is the most common usage. I've updated my answer.